# converting image-based pdf to image file (png/jpg) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, image-processing

I want to covert image-based PDF to image(.png/.jpg) file in Python, so I can further use this image for exacting tabular data form it.
I don not want to run the code from command line.

I am currently using Python 3.7.1 version and Pycharm IDE.

I have tried the code provided on stackoverflow but nothing works, it runs but unable to extract image form image-based PDF file.
Below is the link for it.
[Extracting images from pdf using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56374258/extracting-images-from-pdf-using-python/56375072#56375072)

Also, tried the code from dzone.com, below is the link but nothing works
https://dzone.com/articles/exporting-data-from-pdfs-with-python

Below are the image-based PDF file links:

link1:
https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/190390001_sd.pdf

link2:
https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Customer+Drawing%7FDT04-12PX-C015%7F-%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_CD_DT04-12PX-C015_-.pdf%7FDT04-12PA-C015

Please suggest any solution for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert PDF to Image using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60701262/convert-pdf-to-image-using-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184239/extract-a-page-from-a-pdf-as-a-jpeg

Comment: thank you joe, this link is very helpful to me, this is what i was searching for long time

Comment: If it is a solution to your question please close / delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pdf2image` library converts pdf to images. As looking at your pdfs they are just images nothing else, you can convert the page to image

*Install*

`pip install pdf2image`

Once installed you can use following code to get images.

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
pages = convert_from_path('pdf_file', 500)

# Saving pages in jpeg format

for page in pages:
    page.save('out.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

Comment: hello kuldeep, I am getting above error while running the code, I have also installed the pdf2image python module, but still getting this error

Comment: You will need `poppler`, check here: https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image

Comment: thank you kuldeep, your code is now working fine after installing poppler